# Admin and user login using one login form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do admin and user login using one login form. but i keep getting error 'Sequence contain no element'. I used the code below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(CustomerAccount user, Admin admnLogin)
{
   using (ProjDbContext db = new ProjDbContext())
    {
        var usr = db.CustomerAccounts.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
        var admn = db.CustomerAccounts.Single(u => u.Email == admnLogin.Email && u.Password == admnLogin.Password);

        if (usr != null)
        {
           Session["CustId"] = db.CustomerAccounts.Single(x => x.Email == user.Email).CustId;
           Session["Email"] = usr.Email.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("TicketForm");

        } 
        else if (admn != null)
        {
            Session["AdminId"] = db.Admins.Single(x => x.Email == admnLogin.Email).AdminID;
            Session["Email"] = usr.Email.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("AdminPanel");

        }            
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email or Password is wrong.");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Anyone can help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to LINQ ,you can usually see this error because of you are using the First() or Single() command, instead of FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault().

Example:

Session["CustId"] = db.CustomerAccounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email).CustId;

Session["AdminId"] = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == admnLogin.Email).AdminID;

Comment: This will throw `NullReferenceException` if the `...Default()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Fixing LINQ Error: Sequence contains no elements](https://blogs.msmvps.com/kevinmcneish/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements/), this exception occurs when using `First()` or `Single()` that contains empty data. The usual way to fix this exception is using `FirstOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault()` or `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but take note that reference objects contains null value when `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` is used and should be checked before accessing any members inside it.

Therefore, your session variable assignments should be check against null value like below example:

```
// Customers
var cust = db.CustomerAccounts.Single(x => x.Email == user.Email);

if (cust != null)
{
   Session["CustId"] = cust.CustId;
}

// Admins
var admin = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == admnLogin.Email);

if (admin != null)
{
   Session["AdminId"] = admin.AdminID;
}
```

For C# 6 and above, you can use [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) when accessing property members after `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
// Customers
Session["CustId"] = db.CustomerAccounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email)?.CustId;

// Admins
Session["AdminId"] = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == admnLogin.Email)?.AdminID;
```